# Анимация вылета за предел панели

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

вопрос такой: есть у меня панель 1, на ней расположена панель 2, внутри которой панель(и) 3. На гифке все помечено цифрами.

Собственно хочу сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку можно было "листать" панельки под номерами 3. Если просто их двигать, то они будут идти поверх Панели номер 1, это не пойдет, нужно чтоб они уходили под панель 2. Объяснил не очень, но по гифке думаю понятно. Гуглил, ничего не нашел, прошу помочь, провозился с этим 3 часа, толку 0.
[image: ity]

Answer (score 0):

Если это `UI`, то тут изи.

```
Canvas
    Rect2 (Компаненты: Image, Mask)
        Rect3A (Image)
        Rect3B (Image)
        Rect3C (Image)
        ...
```

Хотя для промотки `UI` элементов есть `Scroll View`, что бы можно было проматывать *drag* тачем или мышкой.